# crontab run shell script that write user history into a log file

Tags: shell, cron

I write the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history
file=$(date "+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S").txt
history  > /home/sandipon/$file
cat  /home/user/$file
sshpass -p my_password scp  /home/user/$file host:/home/test/$file
```

And scheduled it by cron:

```
*/2 * * * *  /home/user/history.sh
```

But it provides a blank file.

Comment: do not use `~` in your crontab scripts. Instead, use full paths. Also, provide a binary in your cron expression. Take a look at "debugging crontab" in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment from fedorqui is correct.
Also, you shoud add a username in crontab file (if you use "/etc/crontab").
For example:

```
*/2 * * * *  USERNAME  /bin/bash /home/user/history.sh
```